# Webpack typescript ionic3 angular 4 typing errors

Tags: angular, typescript, typescript-typings

I am building ionic3 angular 4 application using webpack builder.

There are two process running.
1. Run code in browser.
2. Make build for the devices.

If i add this line of code

let a = {}

let a = {}

The compiled angular 4 typescript does not give any error in the browser or webpack console for duplicate variable declaration. But while doing complitation using CORDOVA=true webpack --config webpack.stage.js --env.aot=true --env.name=staging for mobile builds. It gives the duplicate variable errors.

I want to see that error while doing the code and on browser or in webpack running console. Is there a way to see those there?

Comment: Maybe in your tsconfig?

Comment: yes but same tsconfig is used by the both processes